# Save contour images generated in a loop as a single pdf file (2 images per page preferably)

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation, contour

I have written this code which will generate a number of contour plots, each of which corresponds to a single text file. I have multiple text files. Currently, I am able to generate all of the images separately in png format without any issues.
When I try to save the images as a pdf file, it is saving only the last image generated in a loop.I tried using the PdfPages package. This question is similar to the one that I posted before but with a different question. [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834109/to-obtain-the-correct-orientation-of-the-contour-plot-and-save-the-plots-as-sepe)

Issue: I want to able to generate all of the images into a single pdf file automatically from python. So for eg. if I have 100 text files, then I want to save all of the 100 images onto a single pdf file.Also ideally I want to save 2 images in a single page in the pdf file. There are some questions in SO about this, but I couldn't find an appropriate solution for my issue. Since I have many case for which I have to generate the images, I want to save them as a single pdf file as it is more easier to analyze them. I would appreciate any suggestions/advice to help me with this.

This is link for the sample text file [Sample Text](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hemqyerwu1fx6s7/AAAjnNIQ5DGQrtZvnnVXoBKXa?dl=0)
ges

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate  import griddata
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
path = 'location of the text files'
FT_init = 5.4311
delt = 0.15
TS_init = 140
dj_length = 2.4384

def streamfunction2d(y,x,Si_f,q):       
  with PdfPages('location of the generated pdf') as pdf:  
        Stf= plt.contour(x,y,Si_f,20)
        Stf1 = plt.colorbar(Stf)
        plt.clabel(Stf,fmt='%.0f',inline=True)
        plt.figtext(0.37,0.02,'Flowtime(s)',style= 'normal',alpha=1.0)
        plt.figtext(0.5,0.02,str(q[p]),style= 'normal',alpha=1.0)
        plt.title('Streamfunction_test1')
        plt.hold(True)       
        plt.tight_layout()
        pdf.savefig()

        path1 = 'location where the image is saved'
        image = path1+'test_'+'Stream1_'+str((timestep[p]))+'.png'
        plt.savefig(image)    
        plt.close() 

timestep = np.linspace(500,600,2)
flowtime = np.zeros(len(timestep))
timestep = np.array(np.round(timestep),dtype = 'int')
###############################################################################
for p in range(len(timestep)):   
        if timestep[p]<TS_init:
            flowtime[p] = 1.1111e-01
        else:
            flowtime[p] = (timestep[p]-TS_init)*delt+FT_init 
        q = np.array(flowtime)

        timestepstring=str(timestep[p]).zfill(4)
        fname = path+"ddn150AE-"+timestepstring+".txt"
        f = open(fname,'r')
        data = np.loadtxt(f,skiprows=1)
        data = data[data[:, 1].argsort()]
        data = data[np.logical_not(data[:,11]== 0)]                                                                
        Y  = data[:,2]  # Assigning Y to column 2 from the text file
        limit = np.nonzero(Y==dj_length)[0][0]
        Y  = Y[limit:]

        Vf  = data[:,11] 
        Vf  = Vf[limit:]
        Tr  = data[:,9]  
        Tr  = Tr[limit:]

        X  = data[:,1]  
        X  = X[limit:]
        Y  = data[:,2]  
        Y  = Y[limit:]
        U  = data[:,3]  
        U  = U[limit:]
        V  = data[:,4]  
        V  = V[limit:]
        St = data[:,5]  
        St  = St[limit:]
        ###########################################################################     

        ## Using griddata for interpolation from Unstructured to Structured data
        # resample onto a 300x300 grid        
        nx, ny = 300,300

        # (N, 2) arrays of input x,y coords and dependent values
        pts = np.vstack((X,Y )).T
        vals = np.vstack((Tr))
        vals1 = np.vstack((St))

        # The new x and y coordinates for the grid
        x = np.linspace(X.min(), X.max(), nx)
        y = np.linspace(Y.min(), Y.max(), ny)
        r = np.meshgrid(y,x)[::-1]

        # An (nx * ny, 2) array of x,y coordinates to interpolate at
        ipts = np.vstack(a.ravel() for a in r).T 

        Si = griddata(pts, vals1, ipts, method='linear')
        print(Ti.shape,"Ti_Shape")
        Si_f = np.reshape(Si,(len(y),len(x)))
        print(Si_f.shape,"Streamfunction Shape")        
        Si_f = np.transpose(Si_f)        
        streamfunction2d(y,x,Si_f,q)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** : As you mentioned matplotlib is probably able to handle everything by itself using [`PdfPages`](http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_pdf_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages) function. See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17788764/1219073). My original answer is a hack.

I think the error in your code is that you are creating another `PdfPage` object each time you go through the loop. My advice would be to add the `PdfPage` object as an argument to your `streamfunction2d` function and create the `PdfPage` object once and for all before the loop (using a `with` statement as in the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_pdf_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages) seems a good idea).

Example:

```
def streamfunction2d(y,x,Si_f,q,pdf):       
    # (...)
    pdf.savefig(plt.gcf()) 

with PdfPages('output.pdf') as pdf:
   for p in range(len(timestep)): 
      # (...)  
      streamfunction2d(y,x,Si_f,q,pdf)
```

---

**Original answer:**
Here is a quick and dirty solution using the [`pdfunite`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/poppler-utils) software.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import subprocess
import os 

X = np.linspace(0,1,100)
for i in range(10):
    # random plot
    plt.plot(X,np.cos(i*X))

    # Save each figure as a pdf file.
    plt.savefig("page_{:0}.pdf".format(i))
    plt.clf()

# Calling pdfunite to merge all the pages
subprocess.call("pdfunite page_*.pdf united.pdf",shell=True)

# Removing temporary files
for i in range(10):
    os.remove("page_{:0}.pdf".format(i))
```

It uses two things:

- You can save your figures as pdf using matplotlib's `savefig` command.
- You can call other programs using the `subprocess` library. I used `pdfunite` to merge all the pages. Be sure it is available on your machine !

If you want to have several graph by page, you can use subplots.

Alternatively, you could use another python library (such as [pyPDF](https://mstamy2.github.io/PyPDF2/)) to merge the pages, but it would require slightly more code. Here is an (untested) example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

# create an empty pdf file
output = PdfFileWriter()

X = np.linspace(0,1,100)
for i in range(10):
    # random plot
    plt.plot(X,np.cos(i*X))

    # Save each figure as a pdf file.
    fi = "page_{:0}.pdf".format(i)
    plt.savefig(fi)
    plt.clf()

    # add it to the end of the output
    input = PdfFileReader(file(fi, "rb"))
    output.addPage(input.getPage(0))

# Save the resulting pdf file. 
outputStream = file("document-output.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
```

Comment: In my code, I added image1 = path1+'test_'+'Stream1_'+str((timestep[p]))+'.pdf' and then used plt.savefig(image1). Now it is saving multiple pdfs and the merge function is not working. Could you please add your solution to my code? Thank you

Comment: If you  have multiple files you are on the right track: you only need to merge now. (You can clean up afterward by removing all the one page pdf using `os.remove` as I added in my example code). Which merging method did you use ? What is the error message ?  (Do you either have `pdfunite` or the `pypdf` library installed ?)

Comment: I added a possible solution that relies only on matplotib as you originally intended.

Comment: Thank you Geeklhem. I now know how different techniques can be used to complete our task. I will try out your new solution. By the way, your pdf unite solution works, but when it merges the pdf, the files are not combined in order. If there is a way to do this, please let me know. I will accept your answer. Thank you very much.